# WebMatrix: increasing upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Tags: php, windows-8.1, webmatrix, iis-express

I have installed joomla from webmatrix app gallery. 
I need to increase the default upload size (2M) to 6M but I cannot find the PHP folder.

I am using windows 8.1 pro 64bit

I have checked the following directory:
C:\Program Files\IIS Express

just to be sure I checked the 32 bit folder too
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express 
But I couldn't find the location. Searching the Program files is very time consuming (As my Program File folder is not indexed) so if you could direct me to the location I would be very thankful.

By the way I have PHP v 5.4 and 5.5 installed within webmatrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a PHP folder in the directories you listed above. Inside this directory will be a version number directory. In that directory will be the php.ini.

ie `PHP\v5.4\php.ini`

Alternatively create a new php file in webmatrix and add the following line into it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Run the page and you will get a list of php environment variables. One of them will be the location of the php.ini file.

Comment: I didn't find the PHP folder however the phpinfo(); did the trick I missed out the php.ini location. thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

`php.ini` file path is:

```
C:\program files (x86)\iis express\PHP\php.ini
```

and if you want to increase size of your uploads then change `Upload_max` in the php.ini file from `2m` into you want for example `1024M`